# Animating the css of an image giving different result

Tags: jquery, css

I have a menu and a small bar that follows which `<a>` tag I hover in my menu.

The small bar is an image and I am animating its CSS with the jQuery animate function.

My problem is that my small bar position is a little bit different when I use a different 
browser or a different resolution.

I need that bar to always fit perfectly.

The problem with [my fiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net/EVa8u/5) is that I use an image

Comment: Show us your code please ... or better create a http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Post the CSS and jQuery code you have (preferably just the important part). It's impossible to guess which of the trillion reasons is the cause if you don't show any code or link. I'd use a css reset/normalizer stylesheet if it was just cross-browser issues, but as it is also affected by resolution then it probably has to do with your overall page design or code.

Comment: Fix your fiddle please. Switch Framework to jQuery and include the rest of your js via "add resources".

Comment: I tried "fixing" the fiddle for you, http://jsfiddle.net/EVa8u/5/ (scroll to the right and mouseover links), I guess it's more clear what OP is trying to do.

Comment: Sorry i had problem with Fiddle i've never used it before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to [repeat yourself](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) for each item, instead you can write a single function for all of them:

```
$("#smallMenu a").mouseover(function(){
    var $this = $(this),
        os = $this.offset();
    $("#smallBar").clearQueue().animate({
        left: os.left,
        top: os.top + $this.height(),
        width: $this.width()
    });
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/EVa8u/10/)

This will set the bar in the same `left` position of the hovered link - `os.left` - and just below the hovered link itself - `os.top + $this.height()` -, with the same width of the link - `$this.width()`, independently of its position or size in the page. You can adapt it your needs (you can add or take pixels of the positions and width as well).